# How does a halogen react in an electrophilic substitution reaction

Tags: electrophilic-substitution

[image]

From what I understand, electrophiles are electron deficient and therefore would be attracted to the electron-rich benzene ring. So would the correct answer be A?

Comment: The double bond in D is also electron rich

Answer (score 1):

A is correct because the question specifically says an electrophilic substitution reaction (D will also react, but it's an electrophilic *addition* reaction). However, you also need a Lewis acid catalyst like FeCl$_3$. This is because, while the delocalised system of electrons in benzene is indeed electron rich, the fact that it's aromatic (there is a system of pi electrons delocalised throughout the ring) makes it very stable.
The mechanism of the bromination of benzene is shown below (image from Wikipedia as I don't have ChemDraw on this computer). The mechanism is the same for Cl$_2$.

[image: Mechanism of halogenation of benzene]

Comment: The OP did not ask about electrophilic aromatic substitution.

Comment: No, but they asked which molecule reacts via an electrophilic substitution mechanism. In this case it happens to be an electrophilic aromatic substitution, and I thought providing the mecanism would help to explain how this happens.